# Como traçar rotas em uma aplicação C# Windows Forms a partir da latitude e longitude

Tags: c#, winforms, maps, rotas

Olá, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma exibir uma rota a partir da latitude e longitude que estão no banco de dados em uma aplicação C# Windows Forms. Já procurei na web e consegui acha alguma coisa parecido com o que preciso,
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/0e0b98ce-be58-4b8a-901d-8a05f9dd54f0/gerar-rotas-no-google-maps?forum=504 Mas ainda não consegui entender muito não. O código está ficando da seguinte forma:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace GSD
{
    public class Class1{

        public Class1(){

        }

        public void AbreGoogleMaps(double _lat1, double _long1, double _lat2, double _long2)
        {
            string defaultBrowserPath = GetDefaultBrowserPath();

            try
            {
                Process.Start(defaultBrowserPath, string.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={0},{1}&daddr={2},{3}", _lat1, _long1, _lat2, _long2));
            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }
        }

        private static string GetDefaultBrowserPath()
        {
            string key = @"htmlfile\shell\open\command";

            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key, false);

            return ((string)registryKey.GetValue(null, null)).Split('"')[1];
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta implementação que você demonstrou pode até funcionar, só que ela abre o browser do usuário com a rota mapeada. Desta forma você não tem um controle desejável das implementações e dificulta um pouco a personalização dos mapas. Existe uma biblioteca Open Source que se chama GMaps.NET (Great Maps .NET) que implementa os recursos de criação do mapa em um formulário, existe também a possibilidade de se usar a API do google para pegar as coordenadas da rota desejada, acredito que se você realizar uma implementação unindo as duas tecnologias, dá para fazer algo bem completo e funcional, abaixo os links para verificação:

https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=pt-br